# How to add class to every second element, after the filter runs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I run this code for my filtred portfolio and I need to add class every second element of the filtered results. This is what I tried so far (with no luck). Ok I know this is simple but some how I can't make it work!

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="all">All</button>
<button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="hdpe">HDPE Pipes</button>
<button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="sprinkle">Sprinkle Pipes</button>


<div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe">
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
</div>

<div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe">
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
</div>

<div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter sprinkle">
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
</div>

<div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter sprinkle">
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

JQUERY

//PROJECT FILTERS

```
$('.filter-button').click(function(){
var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');

if(value == 'all')
{
$('.filter').show('1000');
}
else
{

$('.filter').filter('.'+value).removeClass('even').removeClass('odd').removeClass('visible');


$('.filter').not('.'+value).hide('3000');
$('.filter').not('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').removeClass('visible');

$('.filter').filter('.'+value).show('3000');
$('.filter').filter('.'+value).addClass('visible');

$( ".visible" ).filter( ":even" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
//$( ".visible" ).filter( ":even" ).addClass( "even" );

}
});

if ($('.filter-button').removeClass('active')) {
$(this).removeClass('active');
}
$(this).addClass('active');
```

The code is used from the exampe above
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/portfolio-gallery-with-filtering-category

Thanks in Advane for your comments and help

Comment: which class you are trying to add on each second element of filtered result

Answer (score 1):

this can run from the button bellow : Run code snippet

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <!--<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script> 
  <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<!-- give the jquery manual to everybody !!! -->
<!-- https://github.com/Yahasana/jqdoc-parser  -->

<style type="text/css">
.even{
 background-color:red;
}
.normal{
 background-color:white;
}
</style>



  <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="all">All</button>
<button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="hdpe">HDPE Pipes</button>
<button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="sprinkle">Sprinkle Pipes</button>


<div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe">
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
</div>

<div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe">
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
</div>

<div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter sprinkle">
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
</div>

<div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter sprinkle">
<img src="http://fakeimg.pl/365x365/" class="img-responsive">
</div>





<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function(){
 




$('.filter-button').click(function(){
var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');

if(value == 'all')
{
$('.filter').show('1000');
$(".filter").removeClass("even").addClass('normal');
}
else
{
/*
$('.filter').filter('.'+value).removeClass('even').removeClass('odd').removeClass('visible');


$('.filter').not('.'+value).hide('3000');
$('.filter').not('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').removeClass('visible');

$('.filter').filter('.'+value).show('3000');
$('.filter').filter('.'+value).addClass('visible');

$( ".visible" ).filter( ":even" ).css( "background-color", "red" );*/
//$( ".visible" ).filter( ":even" ).addClass( "even" );


            $(".filter").not('.'+value).hide('3000');
            
   
   
   $('.filter').filter('.'+value).show('3000');

   var iii=1;
$('.filter').filter('.'+value).each(function(index) {
    //alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
console.log(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
if((iii/2)==parseInt(iii/2)){
 console.log('yep');
 //$(this).css( "background-color", "red" );//works but is more good ideea to add a class like you tryed
 $(this).addClass("even");
};
iii++;
});



}
});

if ($('.filter-button').removeClass('active')) {
$(this).removeClass('active');
}
$(this).addClass('active');










var index=1;
 $('input').each(function(index) {
  $(this).before(index);
  $('textarea').val($('textarea').val()+'\n'+$(this).val());
  index++;
 });

});
//-->
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```